# Inverse image of the center of a modification between complex space (set of non-biholomorphic points) is of codimension $\ge$ 1.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-geometry

A theorem in *Demailly II.10.2* states that a modification induces an isomorphism for the sheaves of meromorphic function. The definition of modification map is following

> An analytic morphism $F : X \rightarrow Y$ is said to be a modification if $F$ is proper and there exists a nowhere dense closed analytic subset $B\subset Y$ such that the restriction $F: X\backslash F^{-1}(B) \rightarrow Y\backslash B$ is an isomorphism.

A critic point in the proof is if $h$ does not vanish on an open subset in a neighborhood of $y \in \Omega \subset Y$ then $h\circ F$ cannot vanish identically on any open subset $W \subset F^{-1}(\Omega)$. However we are not sure whether $F^{-1}(B)$ is nowhere dense.

The first question is how to makes sure $F^{-1}(B)$ is nowhere dense?

After I searched on google I find that we can choose such that $F^{-1}(B) = \{ x \in X : \text{F is not biholomorphic at X} \}$. I find this interesting but I can't find a proper reference. My confusion is what does 'biholomorphic at a point' mean and how can it be true.

Comment: First, can you include a proper reference to the work of Demailly? Second, where is it asserted that $F^{-1}(B)$ is nowhere dense? Biholomorphic at a point means biholomorphic in a neighborhood -- Being holomorphic is a local property, not a punctual property.

Comment: @AmorFati On Demailly's Complex Analytic and Differential Geometry https://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/~demailly/manuscripts/agbook.pdf ,10.2 Chapter II.

Comment: The third line of the proof

Answer (score 0):

Note that $F$ is a proper map and $B$ is a closed nowhere dense set. The preimage of a closed nowhere dense set under a proper map is nowhere dense.

An excellent reference for analytic geometry is (specifically, $\S 6.3$) *Coherent Analytic Sheaves* by Grauert and Remmert. It is quite a formidable text, at least initially, but Grauert and Remmert were definitely the masters of complex analysis in the 20th century.

Comment: What if $F$ maps a compact manifold constantly to a point?